# Without using service workers, how can I send web push notifications?

Tags: web, push-notification, service-worker, web-push

Is there any way to send push notifications without using service workers ?

Answer (score 4):

No, in order to use the [Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API), you need a Service Worker.

Comment: so there is no way to use push notification without service workers ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use various services like Pusher/Pubnub etc. to send push notifications on your behalf. For example using Pusher and Python, you can do something like this:

```
from pusher import Pusher

pusher = Pusher(
  app_id=u'APP_ID',
  key=u'APP_KEY',
  secret=u'APP_SECRET'
)

pusher.trigger(u'test_channel', u'my_event', {u'message': u'hello       world'})
```

Comment: But I do not want to use third party services like PubNub in my project.